# Adding rel attribute to Drupal form submit button

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-6

For some reason I cannot make this work. The **rel** attribute does not get added to the input tag.

```
function voicesofyouth_preprocess_contestentry_node_form(&$vars){

    $vars['form']['buttons']['submit']['#attributes']= array("rel"=>"draft"); 
    //Does not work

    $vars['form']['buttons']['submit']['#attributes']= array("class"=>"draft");
    //But adding a class does work

}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I am completely dumbfounded as to why adding the class works but the rel does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if that code is the exact one as in your module then it's not working because on the second line you actually delete the '#attributes' property you set up in the first line. you should write something like this:

```
$vars['form']['buttons']['submit']['#attributes'] = array(
  "rel" => "draft",
  "class" => "draft"
);
```